# A metric is open in itself

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

For a metric space $X$, I want to find a neighbourhood of any point $p \in X$ which is a subset of $X$. How to find specify that $r$

Comment: Try $r=42$. ${}$

Comment: Any open ball centered at $p$ should do it, no ?

Comment: sorry it was trivial. needs to close.

Comment: @JonasMeyer $42$ is too underrated.

Answer (score 1):

The number $r$ needs to be positive, not $0$ and not negative, in order for this to work.  And that condition is sufficient; no other is necessary.